# Facebook Shop pulling in wrong product thumbnails when linked with Shopify

Tags: image, facebook, product

I have made my website on Shopify, and have linked it with Facebook, but it is pulling in the wrong thumbnails for the products when viewing on mobile. Desktop seems to be fine, but it seems to select either image number 2, 3 or 4, rather than the primary image. 90% of my audience are on mobile devices so this is big problem for me.

This isn't when I try and share my product on Facebook, this is the initial set up when I connect my website/Shopify to my Facebook business page.

Link to website | Link Facebook

I have attached some example images:

[Overview of Products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCGhP.jpg)

[Overview of Collections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSohO.png)

[List of Products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZMzz.jpg)

I'm not a coder, so I'm not able to identify a problem with the code. There has been a few articles floating around whereby the same error occurs when people share their products to Facebook, but this seems to be blanket problem across all of my products.

Is anybody able to offer any advice as it is quite a big problem as it looks like I am selling a load of envelopes!

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: If you want to hire a programmer Stackoverflow is not the right place.

Comment: I'm not looking to hire a live programmer, I'm just looking for advice.

Comment: Then you have to show us the code you have problem with.